# Why deleted memory is unavailable to use? C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, tinyxml

I have a **200 MB** XML file that I am loading using *TinyXML*. My problem is that when the TinyXML object is destroyed, the memory it used will not be reused. I have used a memory leak detector that I have used in other projects, and have manually stepped through the code and have not been able to find any memory leaks, so I don't suspect that leaked memory is the problem.

This code will reproduce the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tinyxml.h>

int main()
{
    char* filename = "../LargeFile.xml";

    {
        TiXmlDocument targetDoc( filename );
        targetDoc.LoadFile();
    }

    char* buf = new char[ 524288000 ];
    delete [] buf;

    return 0;
}
```

Using [Address Space Monitor](http://hashpling.org/asm/) I can see that after `LoadFile()` there is a large chunk of red, then after `targetDoc` is destroyed it is all yellow. Then when the final char buf is allocated it appears in red but over the top of green space rather than the yellow freed from TinyXML. If try to allocate more buffers than there is green address space the application will crash(out of memory). This can be seen in the images below.

[image: After Load]
[image: After Unload]
[image: Char Buffer Allocation]

According to the Address space monitor page *"Free address space is shown in green, reserved addresses in yellow and used (committed) memory regions in red"* So why is the memory that is freed by TinyXML staying *"reserved"* according to Address Space Monitor. What can cause that to happen, and how do I stop it?

**EDIT:**

*"Are you allocating large buffers? If so, then there may be memory fragmentation in the yellow space and there's nowhere that a large contiguous buffer can be allocated"*

Great question however this would indicate that TinyXML has a memory leak and none of my tools have shown there to be one.

**UPDATE**

I made loop that endlessly allocated ints, which eventually appeared to used all the yellow space. However larger allocations don't use it. This indicated to me that there were small leaks that were getting littered through the heap during the parsing of the xml file by tinyXML which fragments the heap in such a way that only objects small enough to fit between the leaks could be allocated in the yellow space. So I searched longer and harder for leaks in TinyXML and still did not find any. Everything seems to be getting freed up correctly, which brings me back to my initial state of confusion.

I am at a loss to explain the problem.

[image: Char Buffer Allocation]
[image: Char Buffer Allocation2]
[image: Char Buffer Allocation3]

Comment: Are you able to allocate 512MB memory without the tinyxml usage?

Answer (score 6):

Are you actually seeing any other indications of memory issues? Reserved memory indicates that the address range is reserved from the OS, but there is no physical memory actually in use. It is nothing to worry about. When you next need memory, it will first come from that reserved space.

Comment: Are you actually seeing any other indications of memory issues? Yes. If i continue allocating a few more buffers, once there is no more free (green) space the new will fail and crash. it wont use the yellow space. Ill edit my question to be more clear.

Comment: @0xC0DEFACE: Are you allocating *large* buffers? If so, then there may be memory fragmentation in the yellow space and there's nowhere that a large **contiguous** buffer can be allocated. Perhaps you could try a lot of small allocations, instead of a few very large ones.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: I am using pretty large buffers, however if there was still allocations in the yellow memory causing a fragmentation issue, that would be a memory leak and my leak detectors and debugging didn't find any leaks. So that should not be the case.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: But I am about to test with small allocations now :)

Comment: making a while(true) new int; loop managed (albeit slowly) to fill the entire yellow region with red using the older memory, so I guess that means that TinyXML does have a leak somewhere within it, that it not getting freed and stopping large blocks being allocated within that space.

Comment: Are you on a 32-bit system? It is definitely possible that the problem is *fragmentation* and not a memory leak.

Comment: Yes I am on a 32 bit system, however i cant see how fragmentation can be the issue without there being memory leaks. The code above is to simple to cause a fragmentation problem without the presence memory leaks. if the TinyXML object doesnt leak than there should be no more fragmentation that there would be creating than deleting a regular int buffer.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like fragmentation, especially if your memory allocator doesn't reclaim big object allocations. Not trying to plug here, but give Hoard a try and see what happens (www.hoard.org) -- Hoard returns large objects to the OS.

Answer (score 4):

Most OSes don't actually release memory back to the OS when a free() is done (Linux does sometimes for large deallocations).  Instead, application's use the OS sbreak() function to grow memory, maintaining a "high water mark".  As long as you're doing the free() for each malloc() then memory's not being leaked, and future allocations will come from the same memory.  Of course, it may be that something inside TinyXML's not doing such matching frees, deliberately or otherwise, e.g.:

- some function in the TinyXML class, or called by it, could have a static local pointer variable that is  initialised to point to newly allocated heap when the function is first called.  If that happens after other routines have allocated a lot of memory for more transient data, then even after the latter memory is freed the static pointer's allocation may cause some fragmentation, preventing allocation of a huge contiguous block in the reclaimed space.

Comment: Good thought with the statics. There are a couple of statics, however they are members variables, and are only POD types, so there should only be one per class which I still don't think could explain the behavior I'm getting.